# After that Visa expired, re-entering US with ESTA to take a flight back to Europe

Tags: visas, usa, esta, french-language

I'm a French citizen with a US J1 visa that will expire in 2 days. In 2 days I will visit Canada, and I would like to re-enter USA 10 days later just to take my flight back to France. I thought it was possible for up to 1 month after visa expiration, but I just heard that I was wrong. Can I make an ESTA to re-enter US, stay 1 day waiting my flight, and leave? And if it is theoretically possible, is it still possible knowing that I do not have much time left?

Comment: Thanks! I just need to see if this 2-year rules applies to me or not now

Comment: The 2-year residency requirement doesn't prevent you from visiting the US or transiting through the US.  If you need more information about the 2-year residency requirement, please refer to [Expatriates.SE], and consider asking a question there if the existing questions aren't adequately helpful to you.